# How do I generate a script for SQLite in Windows 10

Tags: sqlite

These are instructions to generating a script in Linux

"You should start a script by issuing the command

script a2-script

This will create a file a2-script, which will log input and output at the terminal until you stop the script by typing

exit"

How do I do the same thing in windows 10? I tried typing sciprt a2-script in command promt but I get a message saying that the word script is not a recognizable command

Answer (score 0):

The `script` command records everything you type and everything that is output on your Terminal. You can't do that in Windows easily.

The best thing to do is ignore that step and run the rest of the instructions and, when the screen is full, right-click in the window's title bar and choose `edit->mark` and select the text you want, then right-click in the title bar again and click `edit->copy`. Now you have a copy of the window and you can go in a MS-Word document, or any text editor and paste the contents to have a record of what you did.